# Snowflake: как перевести string "Jul2019" в формат DATE?

Tags: postgresql, snowflake

Та в принципе вот и весь вопрос. У меня есть в Snowflake таблице данные в колонке в виде "Jul2019" (формат колонки - string). Мне надо перевести этот string в date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось так:

```
TO_DATE($1:ACTL_MONYY::text, 'MONYYYY')
```